# オブジェクトのマージについて

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascriptで下記の２つのオブジェクトをマージしたいと思っております。
valの値は共通しているので”A”という結果になり、childの値はそれぞれ異なるためどちらの値も残し、マージしたいのですがどのような実装が考えられますでしょうか。

ライブラリはjQueryを使用しております。

マージ元

```
obj1 = {
    val : "A",
    child : [{
        child_val: 'B',
    }]
}

obj2 = {
    val : "A",
    child : [{
        child_val: 'C',
    }]
}

obj3 = {
    val : "D",
    child : [{
        child_val: 'B',
    }]
}
```

obj1,obj2をマージした際に期待する結果

```
obj = {
    val : "A",
    child : [{
        child_val: 'B',
    },{
        child_val: 'C',
    }]
}
```

obj1,obj2,obj3をマージした際に期待する結果

```
obj = 
[{
    val : "A",
    child : [{
        child_val: 'B',
    },{
        child_val: 'C',
    }]
},
{
    val : "D"
    child : [{
        child_val: 'B',
    }]
}]
```

追記：
説明のために簡略化しておりましたがかえってややこしくしてしまっていたかもしれません。
失礼致しました。
やりたかったこととしては、ディレクトリのパスを複数取得し、下記objのような階層構造を作るのが目的でした。

下記のように複数のパスを配列に格納していたとして、

```
[
     "A/B/C/D/E",
     "A/B/C/D",
     "A/B/D",
     "B/B/C/D"
]
```

最終的にobjの構造に変換する

```
obj =
[
    {
        val : "A",
        child : [{
            val : "B",
            child : [
                {
                    val : "C",
                    child : [{
                        val : "D",
                        child : [{
                            val : "E"
                        }]
                    }]
                },
                {
                    val : "D"
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        val : "B",
        child : [{
            val : "B",
            child : [
                {
                    val : "C",
                    child : [{
                        val : "D"
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

上記を実現するためパスごとに階層構造を作成し、最終的にマージしようとした所で躓き、質問させていただいた次第です。

Comment: 一時変数として連想配列を使うのが常道かな。配列がオブジェクトの配列なので、配列の中に既に存在しているかのチェックが自前でやらないといけないのが面倒(jQuery.uniqueも使えないし）。

Comment: 仮に `val` の値が違っていたらどうなるべきなのでしょうか? マージ対象が `child` の配列に限定されるならば、**集合の合成** へと問題を単純化できます。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY
ご回答ありがとうございます。自前でどのように実装するか検討してみたいと思います。

Comment: @KoRoN

ご回答ありがとうございます。
valの値が異なる場合について追記致しました。
また、child内にchildといったようにネストされることもあるためなかなか良い方法が思いつきません…。

Comment: @eos 状況を整理すると、マージに際してキーとして機能すべきプロパティ `val` と、値として機能すべきプロパティ `child` がある、ということで良いのでしょうか? またそれらのプロパティが複数になることはありますか? このケースでは、それらを解きほぐした上で、このケースにspecificなものとして実装したほうが良いというのが、現時点での感想です。汎用的なフレームワークは寡聞にして存じません。

Comment: @eos ほどほどに汎用化しつつ、示された例において動くものを書いてみました。参考になれば。 https://gist.github.com/koron/31777a42ce57c9722469

Comment: @KoRoN 追記しており確認が遅くなってしまい失礼致しました。コードの提示、非常に助かります。参考にさせて頂きます。

Comment: あら? 追記した分、消しちゃいましたか? 回答用意したんですが…

Comment: @KoRoN 再編集した際誤って削除しておりました。再度編集致しました。申し訳ございません。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ディレクトリのパスを複数取得し、下記objのような階層構造を作るのが目的

ということであれば、個別に「オブジェクト化しマージする」のではなく、「最初から目的の構造を作る」ほうが良いでしょう。その際の基本戦略は、ディレクトリを作成するようにで、実際にやってみたコードが以下になります。

```
var input = [
  "A/B/C/D/E",
  "A/B/C/D",
  "A/B/D",
  "B/B/C/D"
];

function addPath(root, path) {
  var items = path.split("/");
  var currDir = { child: root };
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    // 現在の階層に、目的の名前のサブ階層があれば移動、なければ作って移動
    var item = items[i];
    var dir = findDir(currDir, item);
    if (dir != null) {
      currDir = dir;
      continue;
    }
    currDir = makeDir(currDir, item);
  }
}

// 現在の階層から目的の名前を持ったサブ階層を探して返す。
// 線形検索なので効率はお察し
function findDir(curr, name) {
  if (curr.child == null) {
    return null;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < curr.child.length; ++i) {
    var dir = curr.child[i];
    if (dir.val == name) {
      return dir;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// 現在の階層に、サブ階層を作って返す。
function makeDir(curr, name) {
  if (curr.child == null) {
    curr.child = [];
  }
  var dir = { val: name };
  curr.child.push(dir);
  return dir;
}

var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
  addPath(result, input[i]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

この方法のポイントは `findDir` と `makeDir` の両関数になります。目的の構造をディレクトリに見立てて、この2つの関数を定義することで、`addPath` が作られています。ただし、この実装はやや効率がよろしくない面があります。大量のパスを追加する場合は、そのあたりを考慮して改良してみてください。

Comment: 説明不足で2度お手数をかけてしまい失礼致しました。ご教示いただいた内容を参考に実装できそうです。どちらのコードも大変参考になります。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

一度連想配列を作り、それを出力するのはいかがでしょうか？

```js
var path = [
     "A/B/C/D/E",
     "A/B/C/D",
     "A/B/D",
     "B/B/C/D"
];

var root = {};

for(var i=0; i<path.length; i++){
  var dirs = path[i].split('/');
  var temp = root;
  for(var j=0; j<dirs.length; j++){
    var dir = dirs[j];
    if(!(dir in temp)){
       temp[dir] = {};
    }
    temp = temp[dir];
  }
}

function output(target){
  var parent = null;
  for(var name in target){
    var x = {};
    var child = output(target[name]);
    x.val = name;
    if(child != null){
       x.child = child;
    }
    if(parent === null){
      parent = [];
    }
    parent.push(x);
  }

  return parent;
}

var result = output(root);

$('textarea').val(JSON.stringify(result, null, "    "));
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea></textarea>
```